# How to know probability output by a model corresponds to which class?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am studying the third chapter of [*An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Application in R*](https://www.statlearning.com) which discusses classification models. In **section 4.7.3 Linear Discriminate Analysis** (Lab) the model is applied on a dataset named *Smarket* to predict the up and down of the stock market. Here the total number of down and up prediction was done by the following lines of code: `sum(lda.pred$posterior[, 1]>= .5)` and `sum(lda.pred$posterior[, 1] < .5)` and the writers wrote that

> Notice that the posterior probability output by the model corresponds to
> the probability that the market will decrease

and then to verify these line of codes were written:

```
lda.pred$posterior [1:20 , 1]
```

which gives
[posterior probability of 20 observations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeUTg.png)
and

```
lda.class [1:20]
```

which gives [classes corresponding to the probabilities of the observations given above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5QyD.png)

Also when I wrote the line of code (thanks to ISLR online course):

```
data.frame(lda.pred)[1:20, ]
```

which gives [classes and corresponding probabilites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUsQG.png). Here is seen that observations having probabilities < 0.5 are classified as down class and observations having probabilities >= 0.5 are classified as up class.

This all is a bit confusing to me. My question is [in the first case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeUTg.png) how do we know that when the probability is greater or equal to 0.5 the prediction is down? Because using `contrast()` function it is seen that R has created a dummy variable with a 1 for Up which means that the values correspond to the probability of the market going up, rather than down. Again [in the second case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUsQG.png) why observations having probabilities >= 0.5 are classified as up? Don't the first and second case contradict?

Answer (score 0):

You are predicting both, where the posterior probability of "Down" is 1 - "Up". It just so happens that class "Down" is stored in the first column of lda.pred
`lda.pred$posterior [1:20 , 1]`. The probabilities of "Up" are stored in the second column. (`lda.pred$posterior [1:20 , 2]`).